# jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate full calendar plugin (adam Arshaw's). I need to display the month name. When i try to alert month.getMonth(); it shows the numeric value of month. ie. for July month it shows 7. I need to display it as full Month. for eg. Jul or July. How is it possible? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick, dirty solution. Have an array of months

var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

Then get the desired full Month by deducting 1 since our array index starts with 0.

```
months[month.getMonth()-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comments in your previous question:

fullCalendar has a [monthNamesShort](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/monthNamesShort/) array that you can define during the declaration.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
  if(start < date)
  {
     var shortName = this.calendar.options.monthNamesShort[start.getMonth() - 1];
     alert(shortName);
  }
},
```

Just access it through the calendar options.

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks a lot. But in my start date I have time also included. So when comparing start<date it returns false for the current date. The start and date variable has date with time format. So I believe it compares time also. So I think i need to remove the time from those variables so that it will match the date. I am sorry if I am wrong..:)